# Django WebServer During Testing

Tags: django, django-unittest

I'm writing a complicated web application in Django. There are many components. Two in particular, are the Django server (lets call this `Server`), and a C++ application server (lets call this `Calculator`) which serves calculations to `Server`. When `Server` wants a calculation done, it sends a command to a socket on which `Calculator` is listening. Like this:

```
{
    "command": "doCalculations"
}
```

Now, `Calculator` might need different pieces of information at different times to do its work. So instead of passing the data directly to `Calaculator` in the command, it is up to `Calculator` to ask for what it needs. It does this by calling a RESTful API on `Server`:

```
https://Server/getStuff?with=arguments
```

`Calculator` then uses the data from this call to do its calculations, and respond to `Server` with an answer.

The problems begin when I try to do unit testing using Djangos unittest framework. I set up a bunch of data structures in my test, but when `Server` calls `Calculator`, it needs to have this data available in the REST API so `Calculator` can get what it needs. The trouble is that the Django test framework doesn't spin up a webserver, and if I do this manually it reads the data from the real database, and not the test-case.

Does anybody know how to run a unit test with the data made available to external people/processes?

I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need specify the fixtures to load in your test class.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['data.json']

    def setUp(self):
        # do stuff

    def tearDown(self):
        # do stuff
```

Where `data.json` can be retrieved by using `python manage.py dumpdata`.

It will be filled with data from your main db in JSON format.

`data.json` should exist in the `fixtures` folder of the app you are testing. (Create one if necessary).

Comment: thanks very much for the answer! I didn't know about fixtures. I'm currently taking a dump of the DB as we speak. Will loading the fixtures allow my application server (`Calculator` as I've called it) to speak to the django during a test and view this data through a REST API?

Comment: Yes, the Django server will be able to use the same data during the test, that you have in your db now.